# code igniter concatenation in a for loop

Tags: codeigniter-3

i have a codeigniter code like this.

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($acbox);$i++)
{
    $query=$this->db->get('test');
    $queryresult=$query->row_array();
    $emailid=$emailid. ',' . $queryresult['email_id'];
}
```

here i am concatenating all the email ids in a for loop. what i am looking for is to avoid concatenating any email if its already there in the $emailid variable.

```
Right now i am getting output like this.
$emailid=test@test.com,test@test.com,test@test.com,hai@hai.com,hai@hai.com
Expected output
$emailid=test@test.com,hai@hai.com
```

Kindly help

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put `emails` in a variable test this solution:

```
$this->db->select('email_id');         //select only field that we need it
$this->db->group_by('email_id');       //this is important to avoid from duplicating
$this->db->order_by('email_id','asc'); //sort options
$this->db->limit(100);                 //select only 100 rows (optional)

$results = $this->db->get('test')->result();

$emailid = "";
foreach($results as $row)
{
    $emailid = $emailid . ',' . $row->email_id;
}
```

Comment: HI Damon. Thanks for yor reply. i have put only part of my code. i wont be able to change the code in the way you suggested. may i know is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$data ='';
$query=$this->db->get('table_name');
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
    $data .=$row->email.',';

}
return $data;
```